# Microsoft Access Form Save Record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am designing an MS Access 2013 database, and I routinely need to populate a table with three fields. The values to populate it are predictable for the most part, so I have created a form with three text boxes that each have a calculated default value specified. The form is marked for data entry, so a new record is created by default.

Opening the form populates each text area. When all of the default values are acceptable for the new record, I would *like* to simply be able to click `save` or to press `ctrl + s`. However, all save attempts do nothing unless one of the values in one of the text areas has been modified first.

How do I fix this behavior so that nothing in any of the text areas must be manually modified in order to save the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move focus to a field that is editable and bound to the table:

```
Me!SomeField.SetFocus
```

Then call these two commands:

```
Me.Dirty = True
Me.Dirty = False
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I created an On Load event procedure, and now it behaves correctly.